# multiply the no of column values in sql

Tags: sql

i am having a column name as amount in a table . in that 5 amounts are there, i need to calculate the amount of values in 5 rows , those 5 rows amount need to be added and need to show in a single column as a total amount

Comment: Apply the `select Sum(amount) from table` ???

Comment: Learn about aggregate function `SUM`.. [**link here**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

Comment: And UNION ALL at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple [**SUM() function**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) and specify it as a new column with the [**AS** Alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM TableName;
```

This will give you a new column as total of amounts.

And if you want to show other columns and the total amount column in the end you can do it using **nested queries**:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TableName) AS totalAmount FROM TableName;
```